# UWP alternative of some functions

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, uwp, hololens

I am making an app and it's working fine in Unity editor(5.5) with C#4.But when I compile it for Hololens(UWP) it gives following compiler errors.

1. Thread doesn't contain definition for sleep. (I am using               `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);`)
   2 The name EnvironmentVariableTarget doesn't exist in the current context ( I am using

`var currentPath = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH",            EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);`
     ).

So can anyone suggest me the alternative of this function in UWP.

Answer (score 0):

1: Thread.sleep would block a thread. You can use await Task.Delay(1000);
2: Can't access the envoriment variables. Can you explain why you need this?

Comment: I am trying to integrate gstreamer with unity and deploy the app to play video coming through wifi on Hololens. I am using this gstreamer Unity plug-in https://github.com/ua-i2cat/gst-unity-bridge. In the file GStreamer.cs above mentioned both functions are used. I guess environment variable is used to get the dll and access to gstreamer files(though I am not sure). It would be great if you can suggest me alternatives of above function or any other way to stream video on hololens coming through Wifi

Comment: Well there is a very good chance the dll wont even pass WACK and is not compatible with UWP. Best take a look at the windows runtime api's see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.media.aspx

Comment: Isn't there any other way to play live video captured from external camera on Hololens?